# find duplicated files in a directory

Tags: file, go

This is my first Go program. I'm learning the language but it's a bit difficult to understand all the concepts so in order to practice I wrote a code to detect same file. It's a simple program which recursively check for duplicated files in a directory.

but:

how to detect duplicate file in directory  files

the matter isn't directory recursively. the matter is how to compare

Comment: Never used go, does it have a hash map/set/dictionary data structure? You could insert the file name into the structure. Since these structures only allow unique values, you can assume that if the size of the structure didn't change, it must be a duplicate

Comment: The concept is the same in any language, what problem were you having with Go specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sha256 to compare files

example:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
    "flag"
    "runtime"
    "io"
)

var dir string
var workers int

type Result struct {
    file   string
    sha256 [32]byte
}

func worker(input chan string, results chan<- *Result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for file := range input {
        var h = sha256.New()
        var sum [32]byte
        f, err := os.Open(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            continue
        }
        if _, err = io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            f.Close()
            continue
        }
        f.Close()
        copy(sum[:], h.Sum(nil))
        results <- &Result{
            file:   file,
            sha256: sum,
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func search(input chan string) {
    filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        } else if info.Mode().IsRegular() {
            input <- path
        }
        return nil
    })
    close(input)
}

func main() {

    flag.StringVar(&dir, "dir", ".", "directory to search")
    flag.IntVar(&workers, "workers", runtime.NumCPU(), "number of workers")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Searching in %s using %d workers...\n", dir, workers)

    input := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan *Result)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(workers)

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go worker(input, results, &wg)
    }

    go search(input)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    counter := make(map[[32]byte][]string)
    for result := range results {
        counter[result.sha256] = append(counter[result.sha256], result.file)
    }

    for sha, files := range counter {
        if len(files) > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("Found %d duplicates for %s: \n", len(files), hex.EncodeToString(sha[:]))
            for _, f := range files {
                fmt.Println("-> ", f)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tanks , understand! sha256 input size in very big !

Answer (score 1):

You could take the hash of each file body and then compare the hashes in a dictionary/map.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    contentHashes := make(map[string]string)
    if err := readDir("./", contentHashes); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func readDir(dirName string, contentHashes map[string]string) (err error) {
    filesInfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, fi := range filesInfos {
        if fi.IsDir() {
            err := readDir(dirName+fi.Name()+"/", contentHashes)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else {
            // The important bits for this question
            location := dirName + fi.Name()
            // open the file
            f, err := os.Open(location)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            h := md5.New()
            // copy the file body into the hash function
            if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            // Check if a file body with the same hash already exists
            key := fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
            if val, exists := contentHashes[key]; exists {
                fmt.Println("Duplicate found", val, location)
            } else {
                contentHashes[key] = location
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: why md5? md5 effect on all file?

Comment: it's unlikely you'll get a hash collision with any of the hashing algorithms in the standard library. They can all take very large input sizes.